# Extreme risk to upgrade centos

Tags: centos

To be able to use GLIBC_2.14, i need to upgrade my CentoOS6.8 to 7. I found [this link](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CentOSUpgradeTool) where steps are explained.

On step 7 where i need to do:

```
centos-upgrade-tool-cli --network 7 --instrepo=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/
```

the output ends with

```
preupgrade-assistant risk check found EXTREME risks for this upgrade.

Continuing with this upgrade is not recommended.
```

**What should i do and what can happen if i force it ?**

**EDIT**: some more details

1st - Command

```
sudo preupg
```

Display

```
I/O warning : failed to load external entity
"/usr/share/openscap/xsl/security-guide.xsl" compilation error: file
/usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl line 40 element import xsl:import
: unable to load /usr/share/openscap/xsl/security-guide.xsl

I/O warning : failed to load external entity
"/usr/share/openscap/xsl/oval-report.xsl" compilation error: file
/usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl line 41 element import xsl:import
: unable to load /usr/share/openscap/xsl/oval-report.xsl

I/O warning : failed to load external entity
"/usr/share/openscap/xsl/sce-report.xsl" compilation error: file
/usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl line 42 element import xsl:import
: unable to load /usr/share/openscap/xsl/sce-report.xsl OpenSCAP
Error:: Could not parse XSLT file
'/usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl' [oscapxml.c:416] Unable to open
file /root/preupgrade/result.html Usage: preupg [options]

preupg: error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/root/preupgrade/result.html'
```

2nd - Command

```
sudo rpm --import http@//mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

This displays nothing. Maybe no errors message means everything works?

Comment: Do you have any details on this? Such as *why* it's an extreme risk? Also, clone your server to a lab environment and upgrade there. This isn't something to be done in production without having tested it first.

Comment: sorry if i'm not realy clear, i'm not really good to understand what's going on behind upgrade with command-line. I'll try again and i'll edit step by step errors encounter

Answer (score 3):

At the link you quoted, https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CentOSUpgradeTool, there is a warning as the top of the page:

> **DO NOT USE this tool. Warning: use of this tool is currently BROKEN as several system-critical packages are of a higher version number in CentOS 6.7 than they are in CentOS 7 so those do not get upgraded correctly. This renders yum and several other system tools non-functional.**

Reading further, it explains the risk levels:

> There are several levels of inplace upgrade risks. Any level higher than "slight" means you will get not a 100% functional upgraded system, although the inplace upgrade tool `centos-upgrade-tool` may pass.
>
> The available risk assessment levels are:
>
> - [...]
> - Extreme - We found an incompatibility which makes the inplace upgrade impossible. It is recommended to install a new system with the help of the preupgrade-assistant remediations.

I think that says it all, really. Don't upgrade using this tool!

Comment: indeed but how to do that so ? every link use redhats-upgrade-tool: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-upgrade-centos-6-to-centos-7 or http://www.shaunfreeman.name/upgrading-centos-6-5-to-centos-7-2/